# Argument of type partial is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to update partial property of one of interface in TypeScript as below

```
interface details{
  name: string,
  phonenumber: number,
  IsActive: boolean
}

let pDt: Partial<details> = {IsActive: false};
```

and when i am trying to pass it one of the method which has `details` as parameter, it is giving below issue "**Argument of type Partial is not assignable to parameter of type 'detail'**".

What's wrong here and how to correct?

Comment: Your methods would also need to have Partial<details> as parameter. If you just have "details", TypeScript assumes that all fields are set, which is not the case. So you need function f(det: Partial<details>) to make sure that within the method you check if fields are actually there

Comment: @ddprrt `export const callMe = (detailsMe: <Partial>details): AppThunk => (console.log("Hi"))`, i am getting syntax error here, what's wrong?

Comment: It's supposed to be `Partial<details>`, not `<Partial>details`.

Comment: Btw. it's good practice to start interface name with capital letter and to start property name with lowercase.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Argument of type Partial is not assignable to parameter of type 'detail'

You can't assign a Partial of a type to the original type you made the partial from.

```
interface Details{
  name: string,
  phonenumber: number,
  IsActive: boolean
}

let partialDetails: Partial<Details> = {IsActive: false};
let details: Details = partialDetails // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCITHYAbAzgbwChlkQ4BbCALmVzClAHMAaY5ABwAsB7ECEAK7kARtBqCR0ViQCSuAIIIwwAG7Vkw7t2wQ4IQgF9ChHWA5woyuNnSYcuGgAULV7AB5bWPAD5kAXmR8OUVlNRp4PAgDAG4TDGQAEwwvBzRk+39zS2BrTwyAenzkQiA)

This makes sense because `Details` expects a value on all properties, but `Partial<Details>` can omit *any* of those properties. This makes the partial incompatible with the whole type you made a partial of.

There's no easy "fixing" this. It depends on your app's logic. If you have a function that expects a whole `Details` then you have to pass it a whole `Details`, a `Partial<Details>` will not do.

Answer (score 16):

You can, in your case if you want to use Partial, cast it like this:

```
interface Details{
  name: string,
  phonenumber: number,
  IsActive: boolean
}

let partialDetails: Partial<Details> = {IsActive: false};
let details: Details = partialDetails as Details;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you intend to fill in extra fields on `details` later which is a very common JavaScript pattern just do this:

`let pDt = {IsActive: false} as details;`

Typescript is great when it's helping but it can often readily get in the way as well if you go overboard.