# Partial and extends not working as (I) expected

Tags: typescript-generics

The question is simple, why doesn't this work?

```js
type FooData = {
  p: string;
}
const foo = <T extends FooData>() => {
  const not_working: Partial<T> = { p: "foo" }; // why is this not valid?
}
```

Error on `not_working`: Type '{ p: "foo"; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<T>'.(2322)

I would expect this to be valid because `T extends FooData` which ensures `T` has a `p:string` property.

Se in the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAIgQ2MqBeKBvAUFKMALigGdgAnASwDsBzAblwF9dcBjOG8qAMwUxQAPABUoEAB7AINACalYCFGgB8ACgCUmFTnxRO3YFBpxgAfQDucCgGtadEgAVkFYFWQAbUTqzZCJACJ%20OACoZgYoAHpIqAsACxAoKgVgOOTjUygAN08qWQB%20FlwgA).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63509948/7172604) explains the issue (give it a vote).

The issue is that as `Partial<T>` is expecting not only a Partial of FooData, but also a Partial of T. As it doesn't know what T is, `Partial<T>` could be anything.

Rather than using `Partial<T>`, why not use `Partial<FooData>` or maybe just `FooData` directly?

Comment: I think the answer in the link is somewhat different. It's about you can't assign Partial<T> to T which makes sense. I still think my question is valid, because T can't be anything. T extends FooData. The foo method must be called with any unknown type T which at least has the properties of FooData.

Comment: What about this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59279796/typescript-partial-of-a-generic-type. It mentions https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13442, which explains why it can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

I think actually [19388](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19388) is a duplicate. The issue is that i TypeScript you can have a type that is more specific than `string` like `{p: "A"}` which could be used as `T` but would conflict with the body of the function.